# Using CanCan to authorize_resource, but don't want it for all actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, before-filter

I'm using Devise and CanCan with Rails 4. Both working great, but I don't want either to be in effect for 2 specific actions of a controller. So I do the following for Devise:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:check_in_list, :check_in]
```

This requires the user to be logged in for all exceptions **except** the `check_in_list` and `check_in` actions. Works exactly as I intended. The problem is when I add `authorize_resource`:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:check_in_list, :check_in]
authorize_resource
```

Now if I try to go to the `check_in_list` or `check_in` pages, it redirects me to log in. Is there something similar to the `except` option for `authorize_resource`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to gem documentation https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions you can use `skip_authorize_resource`:

```
skip_authorize_resource only: [:check_in_list, :check_in]
```

Comment: I'll try it... I'm guessing I would use `only:` instead of `except:` in this case. Seems strange to have the `except:` option on `skip_authorize_resource` and not `authorize_resource`

Comment: yes, for your case 'only' should be used. I've updated the answer. Indeed a little strange, but it's their approach

Answer (score 0):

```
skip_authorize_resource only: [:check_in_list, :check_in]
```